# Inverse Vectorization Vec^-1

Tags: matrices, optimization, control-theory, vectorization

Hope that you will find this post in good health.
I am Mr. Adnan from Pakistan with research background in Control systems. I am working on one problem in which Hadamard weights are using.

During solving that problem, i am facing one problem to calculate inverse [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29)/stacking operator i.e $\text{vec}^{-1}$. I would be highly thankful if could you please guide me that how to calculate for example 
$$\text{vec}^{-1}(Wq)$$ 
where $W$ is non singular matrix and $q$ is controller having state space representation 
\begin{align}
X'&=Ax+Bu, \\
Y&=Cx+Du
\end{align}

I just have two queries to calculate above inverse

1. what should be order of $q$ to calculate inverse vector operator $\text{vec}^{-1}$
2. if order of controller $q$ is know then Please tell me how to solve $\text{vec}^{-1}$, any formula,relation or command.

I Knew these two commands $\text{vec}$ and $\text{vec}^{-1}$ but that is not working in my problem.

-Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Adnan. I edited your post to put the formulas in LaTeX/Mathjax format, I hope you don't mind. I'm still a bit confused about what you are trying to do though - are you following a procedure that exists in a reference like a book or paper? If so, posting a link to the reference would help

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what your problem is?

Let $A$ be defined as:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
Then $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{vec}(A) = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{21}\\ a_{12} \\ a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
As a result the inverse is defined as
$$\operatorname{vec}^{-1}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) = A$$

Now, when I typed this down, I think I understand your problem. You have the matrix $B = Wq$ which is vectorized and want to inverse it. This will only work if you know the size of $W$ and $q$ before they were vectorized. Then you know size which the result should be after the inverse vectorization.

Furthermore, what is $q$ exactly? You say that it is a state space system? What do you imagine the result of $Wq$ to be then?

Comment: Yes exactly.
Suppose W is the 2*2 matrix and q is the controller having state space representation. I know the order of q(suppose 6 states,2 inputs and 2 outputs). Now please tell me that how can i calculate inverse vectorization of W*q ?

Comment: @adnanjaffar again please tell me what you imagine the result of $Wq$ to be because what you are saying does not make sense to me. When $q$ is a state space system. $Wq = \begin{align}
WX'&=WAx+WBu, \\
WY&=WCx+WDu
\end{align}$? Please give a concrete example.